# how to modify .htaccess file to give QUERY_STRING?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below htaccess file in my website and it was working perfectly for last two years. Recently i migrated the server to a new hosting partner and seems it not working as expected. I have confirmed that the server is supporting mod_rewrite module. And i could see the [QUERY_STRING] => is null what ever URL i specify, and all the URLs are routing to the home page. Can any one tell what i need to modify. i saw a lot many answers in stackoverflow and nothing worked for me. I am just a begginer in this htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

# REWRITING index.php AS index #
RewriteRule   ^index/?$   index.php  [NC]

# Route The Pages #
RewriteRule   ^index/([{a-z}]+)/?$   index.php?$1  [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^index/home/([0-9]+)/?$   index.php?home&p_id=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^index/page/([{a-z}{\-\}{0-9}]+)/?$   index.php?page&show=$1  [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^index/gallery/([{image}{video}]+)/?$   index.php?gallery&type=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^index/gallery/([{image}{video}]+)/([0-9]+)/?$   index.php?gallery&type=$1&album=$2  [NC,L]
```

Comment: Why do you have curly braces in your pattern? Can you tell me some URLs that are not working?

Comment: one of the url is tgmvidyaniketan.edu.in/index/gallery/image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are matching `video` or `image` then there is no reason to have `{video}` as `{` and }`will match literally`{video}`.

Have your .htaccess this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# REWRITING index.php AS index #
RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [NC,L]

# Route The Pages #
RewriteRule ^index/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index/home/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?home&p_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index/page/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page&show=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index/gallery/(image|video)/?$ index.php?gallery&type=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index/gallery/(image|video)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?gallery&type=$1&album=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I was just about to post that exact same version - @Ricky you can see a demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=680305d4-dc3c-5d94-8016-1f890e9b0220

Comment: Thanks. But still its not working. it showing home page itself

Comment: @Bananaapple thanks for the site link. i didn't aware of this test scenario

Comment: I have tested and its generating 500 error. My Apache version is 2.2.17

Comment: Define null - are you saying there isn't a query string or it's just `?gallery&type=`

Comment: @Bananaapple when i do echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] it's null. if you visit http://tgmvidyaniketan.edu.in/index/gallery/image you can see it

Comment: @anubhava yes i am also getting the 200. but it is the home page. try http://tgmvidyaniketan.edu.in/index.php?gallery&type=image and it will give a gallery page. The problem is $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] is null when we access tgmvidyaniketan.edu.in/index/gallery/image and i dont know why :(

Comment: Its worked!!!! Thank you so much brother :)  can you tell me what is the difference

Comment: Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/index` is the URL then Apache will serve `/index.php`.

Comment: Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Options +FollowSymLinks
> RewriteEngine On
> Options -Indexes
> ```

The empty query string is consistent with `MultiViews` being enabled (perhaps as a result of a server update). Try disabling `MultiViews` at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
```

If `MultiViews` is enabled then a request for `/index/<something>` would result in an internal subrequest to `/index.php/<something>` and none of your remaining directives will match.

---

However, you do still need to update your regex to something like what anubhava suggests, since your current regex is probably matching a lot more than you intend. But your current patterns are ambiguous. For example, what should `[{a-z}{\-\}{0-9}]+` match? It looks like you perhaps intended it to be a `<letter>-<digit>`? However, it currently matches any combination of letters, digits and hyphens (which is how anubhava has interpreted it)?

Comment: Thanks MrWhite. Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews did the work

Comment: You're welcome. `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) is a common cause of conflict with mod_rewrite directives (when referring to files without the file extension).